# How to have combined activities as one for "Rerun from failed activity" in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Our scenario is that ADF doesn't provide the direct activity for us to manage outer service (spark job) and thus we need to have several activities as one to manage it. Thus the activities would contain steps like get secret, call api to submit job, monitor job, etc.
[image]
**Current design:**
we combine those activities as one pipeline and then call this pipeline to manage spark jobs. We have many spark jobs and they depend on each other. Thus we put the parent pipeline to include several pipelines and they depend on each other. When some of the sub pipelines failed, we want to rerun from failed activity to retrigger it. The issue is that "rerun from failed activity" would skip the activities succeed and rerun from the failed activity. However, for the execute spark job (submit/monitor) if submit activity succeed while monitor fail, then rerun would start from monitor again and this would fail again. Actually we want this combined spark submit pipeline rerun again instead of from the failed activity.

**Question:**
Can we have the spark submit pipeline as a combined unique activity and rerun would always start from the initial instead of from the inner activities? Or several spark submit pipelines together in one parent pipeline, how could we rerun the failed sub pipelines?

Comment: There is a Rerun entire pipeline data pipeline option https://i.imgur.com/7zk3tio.png. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Rerun entire pipeline data pipeline would waste resource and increase SLA, which is not what we want.